# How to find maximum point of multivariate function in C#

Tags: c#, .net, math, numerical-methods

Is there any way of finding the maximum point (values of variables) of multivariate function within specific range of variables using open-source resources?

### Background

I have a code that returns functions, like e.g.:

**0.17 - 0.05*x + 0.06*y - 0.02*x^2 + 0.03*x*y + 0.07*x*y^2**

Range of each variable is known. Now I just have to find value of every variable at the max point.

I have only found libs that allow me to calculate first derivatives in a specific point of a function (e.g. AutoDiff .NET) but it feels that there has to be an easier way of finding the maximum rather than counting countless derivatives at all possible points.

### Note

I'm kinda new to c# and programming in general and I've spent great amount of time finding the answer but unfortunately failed. Any suggestions/insights/help are highly welcome.

Comment: This question has more to do with calculus than programming.  If it's a function of two variables you need only calculate the Jacobean, not "countless derivatives":

Comment: Examine the Eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix of the function.

Comment: There could be more variables than 2. I was asking if there is any library/addition that could do all/most of the "calculus stuff".

Comment: In full generality, this is a constrained optimization problem, which is a vast and fascinating topic (and widely useful as well). Take a look at neos-guide.org, in particular https://neos-guide.org/content/optimization-taxonomy . Good luck and have fun. PS. To the extent that you can describe your problem more specifically, others will be able to suggest specific things to try.

Comment: In general you need that partial derivatives of **f(x,y)** in terms of _x_ and _y_ at any point to find the maxima. Are those given, and if so please show the code where the function and its derivatives are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Where the derivative is null you either have a maximum or a minimum or a inflection point (like the middle of a S). Therefore you must first calculate the nulls of the derivative.

If the second derivative (i.e. the derivative of the derivative) is negative at this point, you have a maximum, if it is positive you have a minimum, if it is null you have an inflection point.

You only have to test points where first derivative is null.

Comment: Yes, I know this. Also, I would have to somehow check boundaries since I want to find maximum of a function in a specific variable ranges (and in this case, there could be max that doesn't meet the deriv=0 condition and still be maximum value). The case is, I'm interested in how to do it programmatically in c# (where rest of the code lasts).

Comment: Just check the values the range start and range end in addition to the places where deriv=0. On how to do it in C# really depends on what you have done so far.